# Force unicode text to fail rendering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, html5-canvas

Title may look weird. What I'm trying to do is draw 2 different Cyrillic letters on a canvas and compare images to check are they the same (I assume if font doesn't support Cyrillic letters same output will be for non-existing letters). Problem comes when I want to test failed Cyrillic letters in a font. No matter what I do, I always get proper letter displayed.

I've loaded google font for which I'm sure it doesn't support Cyrillic letters, but my browser failback and display proper letter using some other default font.

This is the code:

```
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
      body {        
        font-size:24px;
        font-family: 'Lato';
      }
  </style>

  <canvas id="c" width="30" height="30" style="background: red;"></canvas>

  <script>
      var c = document.getElementById('c');
      context = c.getContext("2d");

      context.fillText("\u0402", 15, 15);        
  </script>
```

My question is, is there a problem with the code, and canvas somehow default to it's own font if default font doesn't support Unicode, or I need to setup browser to not to use default font. If later, how to do it?

Comment: It may be a systemwide font that the browser is falling back to. Load up a VM that has never had any fonts installed (just default english) and test it in a browser there.

Comment: I will try that. I'm using mint if that's of any use.

Comment: Installed XP in VM, still showing proper character. I'm really confused, I thought displaying unicode characters in webpage for "fancy" fonts is common problem. I just can't get it.

Comment: Created a JS fiddle for you at: http://jsfiddle.net/e4j3V/

Comment: Showing the character for me too, so Im guessing that its a character thats widely supported on most OS's

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, I guess since it's widely supported, I'm trying to fix a problem where no problem exist :/